# Compilation symbols not used by MSBuild in Azure Pipeline

Tags: c#, azure-devops, msbuild, azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline task that looks like

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'MSBuild $(solution)'
  inputs:
    solution: '$(mainProject)'
    vsVersion: '17.0'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:OutputPath=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) /p:DebugType=full'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

where

```
variables:
  solution: '**/mySolution.sln'
  mainProject: '**/web/myProject.csproj'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: Azure
```

It generates an MSBuild command like

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe" "D:\a\1\s\web\myProject.csproj" 
/nologo 
/nr:false 
/dl:CentralLogger,"....MSBuild.Logger.dll";"RootDetailId=some-guid|SolutionDir=D:\a\1\s\web\|enableOrphanedProjectsLogs=true"*ForwardingLogger,"D:\a\_tasks\...MSBuild.Logger.dll" 
/p:OutputPath=D:\a\1\a 
/p:DebugType=full 
/p:platform="Any CPU" 
/p:configuration="Azure" 
/p:VisualStudioVersion="17.0" 
/p:_MSDeployUserAgent="..."
```

Inside my project I define a constant like
[image]

and the csproj setting looks like

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Azure|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;Azure</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

That constant never makes it into the final build. If I add `/p:DefineConstants="TRACE;Azure"` to my `VSBuild@1.msbuildargs` then everything works great. But why are the constants not respected when defined via my csproj?

Comment: Because `Any CPU` and `AnyCPU` don't match.

Comment: There is an ancient 'issue' that solution files use `Any CPU` (with a space) and projects use `AnyCPU` (with no space). In a solution file, `Any CPU` is mapped to `AnyCPU` for projects. Since you are directly building a project, use `buildPlatform: 'AnyCPU'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition from the project is:

```xml
Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Azure|AnyCPU'"
```

`$(Platform)` is expected to be `AnyCPU` (with no space).

The pipeline variable is:

```yaml
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
```

`Any CPU` (with a space). `Any CPU` and `AnyCPU` don't match. Since you are directly building a project, use:

```yaml
  buildPlatform: 'AnyCPU'
```

There is an ancient 'issue' that solution files use `Any CPU` (with a space) and projects use `AnyCPU` (with no space). When a solution file is built, the `Any CPU` solution platform is mapped to `AnyCPU` for the projects.

The Visual Studio UI shows "Any CPU" which I suppose is friendly but is not the value being passed.

When the file to build has a .sln file extension, use `Any CPU`; otherwise use `AnyCPU`. You could adjust your `buildPlatform` variable based on that logic.

Comment: Of course! What a silly typo. Good eye!